# Remove ', # character from All XML node using XSLT without creating new templete

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove '(single quot) and # from XML file. I need to check all XML nodes. I already have XSLT template that is doing other data extraction. So I can't create another Template in the same XSLT. Also i don't want to call translate function in all node. Is there any easy way to apply translate function in all nodes? and can I apply 2 template in the same XSLT where first template will extract and 2nd template will translate the data?

Is there anyone can help me?
XML Sample:

```
 <Report>
    <ResCountryCode>US</ResCountryCode>
    <Reporting>
        <TIN>
          <TaxIDNo>12456-451</TaxIDNo>
          <TINCountryCode>US</TINCountryCode>
        </TIN>
        <TIN>
          <TaxIDNo>4454-8754-4</TaxIDNo>
          <TINCountryCode>US</TINCountryCode>
        </TIN>
        <OrganizationName>AB'C Ca'r Limi#ted</OrganizationName>
        ....
        ....(other nodes with same ' and # character)
    </Reporting>

</Report>
```

XSLT sample:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:template match="Report">  
    <Finance>
        <Reporting>
            <xsl:element name="ResCode">
                <xsl:value-of select="ResCountryCode" />
              </xsl:element>
              <xsl:for-each select="Reporting/TIN">
                <xsl:element name="TIN">
                  <xsl:attribute name="issuedBy">
                    <xsl:value-of select="TINCountryCode" />
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="TaxIDNo" />
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:element name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="Reporting/OrganizationName" />
              </xsl:element>
        </Reporting>
     </Finance>
 </xsl:template>
```

OutPut:

```
<Report>
     <Finance>
        <ResCountryCode>US</ResCountryCode>
        <Reporting>
            <sfa:TIN issuedBy="US">12456-451</sfa:TIN>
            <sfa:TIN issuedBy="US">4454-8754-4</sfa:TIN>
            <Name>AB'C Ca'r Limi#ted</Name>
            ....
            ....
        </Reporting>
     </Finance>
 </Report>
```

Expected OutPut:

```
 <Report>
     <Finance>
        <ResCountryCode>US</ResCountryCode>
        <Reporting>
            <sfa:TIN issuedBy="US">12456-451</sfa:TIN>
            <sfa:TIN issuedBy="US">4454-8754-4</sfa:TIN>
            <Name>ABC Car Limited</Name>
            ....
            ....(with out ' and #)
        </Reporting>
     </Finance>
 </Report>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing using `xsl:value-of` to get the value of a node, use `xsl:apply-templates` like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Reporting/OrganizationName/text()" />
```

Then, have a template matching `text()` to do the translate in one place

The priority is to ensure it matches before the identity template.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" priority="2">
    <xsl:value-of select='translate(., "#&apos;", "")' />
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Report">  
    <Finance>
        <Reporting>
            <xsl:element name="ResCode">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ResCountryCode/text()" />
              </xsl:element>
              <xsl:for-each select="Reporting/TIN">
                <xsl:element name="TIN">
                  <xsl:attribute name="issuedBy">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="TINCountryCode/text()" />
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:value-of select="TaxIDNo" />
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:element name="Name">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="Reporting/OrganizationName/text()" />
              </xsl:element>
        </Reporting>
     </Finance>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you very much. It works perfectly well.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this kind of thing in XSLT is by a pipeline of transformations. Don't try to do multiple transformations in a single pass over the input; create a pipeline of transformations each of which does one simple job. You will end up with code that is much simpler and easier to debug, and much more reusable, because each step in the pipeline can be reused in other pipelines. (If that sounds familiar, yes, it's a fundamental concept in UNIX shell programming).